# NoDeletePrinter not stopping deletion of printers

Tags: printing, windows-registry

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

NoDeletePrinter REG_DWORD 0x00000001 (1)

GPUpdate. GPUpdate /Force. Log out. Reboot. All that jazz - still able to delete printers.

Any tips?